# Must OpenGL textures be flipped?

Tags: opengl

Suppose I load an array of bytes as RGB from a given file.

I've read that OpenGL likes to store its textures "reversed", and I've seen demo programs storing their images flipped upside down.

So in my program, must I reverse the loaded RGB array byte by byte, or line by line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the Bitmap(*.bmp*) format stores it's lines upside-down. I'm not sure who came up with that, but it's a file-format thing. So well, yes, you must do it if you use your own .bmp loader. You can, however, use one which has already been written which *"upside-downs"* the image for you. Again, it's only a .bmp thing. OpenGL works by default on non-flipped images.

Here's a little trick: If you don't want to change your .bmp loader, you can tell OpenGL to flip your image for you:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();
glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

That's what I meant with "by default". You can turn OpenGL upside-down if you want to. However, this only works if you **only** load .bmp files. Other file formats store their lines properly. Therefore, I prefer the first approach - use a real .bmp loader.

**Just to be clear:** IF you load .bmp files, you **MUST** flip the image either by hand before sending it to OpenGL (which most .bmp loaders do), **OR** send the unflipped image to OpenGL and add the above code before your rendering code.

Comment: Right, indeed all the flipped images were BMPs. But how about how OpenGL takes texture coordinates? (0,0) is at the first pixel on the last line, am I right, and (1,1) is the last pixel on the first line? Don't I need to flip the array for this to be correct?

Comment: Well, it depends! If you just take the raw BMP data and send it to OpenGL, then yes, (0,0) suddenly becomes the first pixel in the first line. If you want (0,0) to become the last pixel in the first line again, you have to flip the array before sending it to OpenGL. An alternative is the Texture-matrix-scaling code above.

Comment: @catfish_deluxe_call_me_cd No! (0,0) is the first pixel in the first line. It's just that in OpenGL the lines of the image are sorted from bottom to top, but the origin is still in the first pixel of the first line of the image data **you** send to OpenGL.

Comment: Actually the DIB file format (that's what it's actually called) support both upwards and downwards row ordering. If the height header field is negative it's downwards, if it's positive it's upwards.

Comment: And remember that the described trick to flip the textures relies on the fixed-function pipeline, which you should not be using by now .. ;)